# Border is overlapping on view : how to set superview opaque

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, calayer

In  my app,

I am taking one button

and adding a  red label as a subview on it.

But the border of button is overlapping on border see the image.

[image]

Here is mycode.

**Category** means green boxed button

And red box is a **UILabel**

I think I

```
 Category *category=[[Category alloc] initWithName:[dict valueForKey:@"category_name"]  identity:[[dict valueForKey:@"category_id"] intValue] imageName:nil];



//Button Formatting.

        [category setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:126.0/255.0 green:187.0/255.0 blue:75.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

       [[category layer] setBorderWidth:3.0];
       [[category layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];

            /*Label Formatting.*/
           category.lblimagesCount=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(category.frame.size.width-22, category.frame.origin.y-18, 26, 26)];

           [category.lblimagesCount setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
           [[category.lblimagesCount layer] setBorderWidth:2.0];

           [[category.lblimagesCount layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];

           [category.lblimagesCount setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];

           [category.lblimagesCount setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
            [[category.lblimagesCount layer] setOpacity:1.0];
           [category.lblimagesCount setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

        [category addSubview:category.lblimagesCount];

        [self.viewHeader addSubview:category];
```

Comment: You displays the number is it a label or button?

Answer (score 1):

```
 category.lblimagesCount.center=CGPointMake(category.frame.origin.x+category.frame.size.width, category.frame.origin.y);
```

add this and in the last add this

```
[self.viewHeader addSubview:category];
[self.viewHeader addSubview:category.lblimagesCount];
```

Comment: this works but I want to include the red label as a part of Green Box, but could not set it as a part of header, actually this views are dynamic so defficult to set position....any othe rsolution please .thanks for replying till now

Comment: @ArpitParekh: what did you mean by " set it as a part of header" ? do you need it as subview ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want redLabel not to overlap category then set its Frame according to "self.view.bounds" this and addSubView on category/Self

Answer (score 0):

try

`[self.viewHeader bringSubviewToFront:category];`

after you added as a subview